# I'm writing my first Android app. What should my .gitignore look like?

Tags: android, git

Title pretty much says it all.  Which files/types should I stop from being checked in?  This is a four-person project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you want to ignore generated and IDE specific files. [This](https://raw.github.com/github/gitignore/master/Android.gitignore) is the .gitignore recommended by GitHub:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
```

If you also keep your keystore in your project folder, you should consider adding that to the gitignore file. It is never wise to check in your keystore to a public (or even private) repository.

Answer (score 0):

that`s mine

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/
.metadata/
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
```